# Is there a standard way of doing RPCs with rabbitmq-c

Tags: c, rabbitmq, rpc, librabbitmq

In the RabbitMQ [tutorials](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html) there's a demonstration of how to do remote process calls in all but C-languages (C, C++). I'm using [rabbitmq-c](https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c) and I'm close to replicating what the Python tutorial is doing, after all `correlation_id` and `reply_to` are available fields in the `amq_basic_properties`.

That been said, I can see the following two methods in the `amqp.h` header:

- `amq_simple_rpc`
- `amq_simple_rpc_decoded`

It's my understanding that these are used internally for the library's communication with the broker (e.g. that how a call to create a queue goes through) but I was wondering whether I can use those directly to support my own remote process calls, i.e. have a function that "lives" in one client and make it callable by another client.

If these methods can't be used like this, is there a standard alternative or a description of how to do routed RPCs with librabbitmq-c? Is my approach of replicating the pika tutorial "sane"?

Answer (score 1):

You're right in your suspicion that `amq_simple_rpc` etc are for low-level client-broker communication. They are indeed unsuitable for (broker-mediated) client-to-client communication.

My opinion is that your approach following the pika tutorial is sensible. I'm afraid I do not know of any standard RPC helper library for librabbitmq-c.